# Shiro custom authentication logic

Tags: java, authentication, jdbc, shiro

I have the following requirements for authenticating a user with Shiro:

1. Username and password must match with that stored in the database. If the username and password do not match then an error message should be displayed indicating authentication failure.
2. Account must be active - a user activates their account via an activation email. If the user's account is not active then an error message should be displayed indicating that they have not clicked the activation email.
3. Account must not be expired - user accounts have an expiry date. If the user's account is expired then an error message should be displayed indicating account expiry.

Note: there are two databases for storing user information. One of them stores authentication information (username, and password) and the other database stores information like when the account expires.

I can easily accomplish the first requirement simply by configuring a JDBC realm in shiro.ini.

I'm guessing some custom Java logic needs to be implemented to accomplish requirements 2 and 3. Any hints about how to implement the above? Would I need to implement a custom realm?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is indeed creating a custom realm.

We had some custom demands aon authentication as well. We implemented this by creating our own custom realm implementation. We extended AuthorizingRealm and overridden the doGetAuthenticationInfo method to check if a user can be checked for logging in. You can put your cases 2 & 3 there.

If you only use shiro in a web environment, you might consider overriding the standation authc filter and override the isAccessAllowed method we you can implement some custom redirection if the user is not yet activated or expired.